# Python battleship game index out of range error

Tags: python

I just started coding about a week ago. I'm trying to code a very simple battleship game. Its doing what I want it to do, but I get an index out of range error about 1 in 10 times when I test it. Any suggestions?

Thanks :)

```
from random import randint, choice

x_cor = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
y_cor = [0,1,2,3,4]

def create_board():
    row = [["O" for i in x_cor] for x in y_cor]
    return row 

board = create_board()

def create_ship(board):
    board[choice(x_cor)][choice(y_cor)] = "*"
    return board

world = create_ship(board)

for i in world:
    print(" ".join(i))
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)  - you have the exact line of your error in your error message (that you do not show  - you only have 30 possible values - put them in one by one and see which ones will throw the error. Then inspect your data and fix it ...

Comment: If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details as per the How to Create a [mcve] page. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: This was an mcve.

Answer (score 1):

change:

```
def create_ship(board):
    board[choice(x_cor)][choice(y_cor)] = "*"
    return board
```

to:

```
def create_ship(board):
    board[choice(y_cor)][choice(x_cor)] = "*"
    return board
```

Alternatively, 
 
change

```
x_cor = [0,1,2,3,4,5] 
y_cor = [0,1,2,3,4]
```

to

```
y_cor = [0,1,2,3,4,5] 
x_cor = [0,1,2,3,4]
```